# Jquery UI multiple dialogs generated from php

Tags: jquery-ui, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm stuck with a problem when using Jquery UI Dialog.
I generate a table from php (while loop), with headers like name,email,comments.
Comments are set to display:none, and i want to show them,only  when i click a button like "View" within the corresponding row. The problem is that jquery will generate multiple dialogs , instead of one.

so, my jquery code looks like (from example):

```
$.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
 $(function() {
 $( ".dialog" ).dialog({
 autoOpen: false,
 show: "blind",
 hide: "explode"
 });

 $( ".opener" ).click(function() {
 $(".dialog").dialog( "open" );
 return false;
});
});
```

! Where .dialog is the class i set to to my comments, and opener is the class i set to my button view.

What should i do to receive only one dialog, corresponding to the clicked row ?
If i click view from row 2, i want dialog with comments corresponding to dialog 2. Not all of them.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

With `$(".dialog").dialog( "open" );` you open ALL dialogs with class `.dialog`. I don't know your HTML, but you should look for the dialog you want to open. So use something like:

```
$.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
 $(function() {
 $( ".dialog" ).dialog({
 autoOpen: false,
 show: "blind",
 hide: "explode"
 });

 $( ".opener" ).click(function() {
 $(this).parent('.dialog').dialog( "open" );
 return false;
});
});
```